# Find documents which is older then specified date range based on list of ids

Tags: elasticsearch

After searching for sometime and seeing some answer not able to quite figure out the query for my requirement

My requirement is i have a list of document ids, what i need to find is the documents which are older than a specified range.

Scenario what i am trying:
total document present 10 documents with id ranging from 1 to 10.
trying to fetch 1,2,3 document if its 7 days older.
if only document 1,2 is 7 days older than it should only return 1 and 2 document and ignore the document 3 (if other documents are there which are 7 days older apart from document with id 1,2,3 it should not return in the result as i am passing the ids in the query).

Documents in index

```
{
  "took": 391,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 3,
    "successful": 3,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 4,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 1.0,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "user",
        "_type": "test",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "title": "string1",
          "publishedDate": "2020-11-13T19:11:13.654Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "user",
        "_type": "test",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "title": "string2",
          "publishedDate": "2020-08-13T19:11:13.654Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "user",
        "_type": "test",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "title": "string3",
          "publishedDate": "2020-11-09T19:11:13.654Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "user",
        "_type": "test",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "title": "string4",
          "publishedDate": "2020-11-02T19:11:13.654Z"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Below is the query i am trying:

```
{
      "query": {
      "bool" : {
        "must" : [
          {"term" : {"_id" : {"value" : "1"}}},
          {"term" : {"_id" : {"value" : "2"}}},
          {"term" : {"_id" : {"value" : "3"}}}
        ],
        "filter" : [
          {"range" : {"publishedDate" : {"from" : "now-7d","to" : "now",
                      "include_lower" : true,"include_upper" : true,"boost" : 1.0
                     }
            }
          }
        ],
        "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
        "boost" : 1.0
      }
    }
    }
```

Ideally it should return document 1 and 2 as only those two documents match with the query but above query doesn't return any result.
i think i am doing something wrong in the query.
can someone please help me with this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you want to retrieve those documents that are max 7 days older than the current date, then it should return only document `1`, as document `2` is older than 7 days.**

Adding a working example with search query and search result

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "_id": [
              "1",
              "2",
              "3"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "publishedDate": {
              "from": "now-7d",
              "to": "now",
              "include_lower": true,
              "include_upper": true,
              "boost": 1.0
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "64906019",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "title": "string1",
          "publishedDate": "2020-11-13T19:11:13.654Z"
        }
      }
    ]
```

**Update 1:**

Your query will also work if you just replace the `must` clause with the `should` clause

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [                 <-- note this
        {
          "term": {
            "_id": "1"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "_id": "2"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "_id": "3"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "publishedDate": {
              "from": "now-7d",
              "to": "now",
              "include_lower": true,
              "include_upper": true,
              "boost": 1.0
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it worked, Thanks a lot @Bhavya. but just for my knowledge what was wrong with my query what i was trying.

Comment: @Sibasishpalo please go through my updated answer. You just need to replace `must` clause with `should` clause.

Comment: already tried the query with should before posting the question. it returns all the documents older than 7 days even if the ids are not mentioned in the query. however your solution works. Thanks